# How can I visualize the multivariable function z = f(x(t), y(t)) in 4 dimensions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, visualization

I am trying to visualize$\ z = f(x(t), y(t))$, and my model is that$\ x, y, z$ depend on$\ t$. The only way that I can visualize this is as a point moving in 3D space. However, wouldn't that be $\ \vec p = \vec f(t)$ ?

Is there any way to visualize the relationship between$\ z$ and$\ t$ as a surface that is changing in time, or is this wrong?

Comment: You're not missing something.  Both of these representations can work.

Comment: Sorry David I realized that I had a more specific question instead of whether or not I was missing something. It's just that whenever I see f(x, y) I think surface, so I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should draw *one* surface $z=f(x,y)$ and think of parametrized curves *on* that surface. That is, given the parametrized curve $(x(t),y(t))$ in the $xy$-plane, you look up to the surface and watch the particle moving along the surface.

You could indeed end up in $4$-space by including the $t$-axis, i.e., plotting $(t,x(t),y(t))$ and then moving into one more dimension with the plot $(t,x(t),y(t),f(x(t),y(t)))$ — still a curve on the surface $z=f(x,y)$.